# Why use indicated airspeed instead of dynamic pressure

Tags: aerodynamics, airspeed

> It uses the difference between total pressure and static pressure, provided by the system, to either mechanically or electronically measure dynamic pressure. The dynamic pressure includes terms for both density and airspeed. Since the airspeed indicator cannot know the density, it is by design calibrated to assume the sea level standard atmospheric density when calculating airspeed.
> ...
> However, at typical civilian operating speeds, the aircraft's aerodynamic structure responds to dynamic pressure alone, and the aircraft will perform the same when at the same dynamic pressure. Since it is this same dynamic pressure that drives the airspeed indicator, an aircraft will always, for example, stall at the published indicated airspeed (for the current configuration) regardless of density, altitude or true airspeed.[4]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicated_airspeed

So we are using this "indicates airspeed" not to fund out how fast we are going, but to find out how much force the airplane is experiencing. That sounds like something for dynamic pressure, not some misindicated airspeed.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: More accurately it sounds like *square root* of dynamic pressure.

Comment: You certainly could have an aircraft with a 'q' meter that reported dynamic pressure in psf, psi, bar, Pa, mmHg, or whatever your chosen units are.  The airplane cares about q, not about V. Pilots like to think in familiar speed units.  MPH or KTS are familiar.  Perhaps they would become familiar with q in psf, but perhaps not. The biggest issue is the 'squared' (or square root, depending on your perspective) relationship between q and V makes some things unfamiliar.    Of course regulations are written for IAS, there are many human reasons to not change.

Answer (score 1):

Because when we are traveling somewhere we want to know when we will arrive.  We can easily calculate that if we know how many nautical miles we are traveling each hour.  A pressure based unit of measure would be relatively meaningless to a pilot.

Comment: You have to convert IAS to TAS anyway, so it wouldn't matter too much how you do it. But back when aircraft flew low it was different, so there is a historical aspect.

Comment: @JanHudec I believe historical aspect is precisely why we use IAS. In my opinion, early aviators would have figured out that instead of directly using dynamic pressure, if they used its square root, it would give a value linear with speed. And afterall, people are generally more familiar with "speed" rather than "dynamic pressure" and so IAS becomes a convention. Maybe you can write your own answer on that :-)

Comment: And how exactly does misIndicated Airspeed tell us when we will arrive?

Comment: @Abdullah, what unit of measure do you propose, and what useful information would it convey?

Comment: Pa? Psi? Unlike (KmIAS) Knots misIndicated Airspeed, it actually tells us why the aircraft is about stall or break up.

Comment: @Abdullah, and Vs or Vne is inadequate because why?  You state "not to find out how fast we are going, but to find out how much force the airplane is experiencing." but my point is that isn't true, we absolutely care how fast we are going.  I know that the faster I go the more drag force is in play, but I want an airspeed indicator to know what my airspeed is.  I don't really care about PSI, I can't convert that to a speed for time/distance calculations.  (FMI, does your use of "we" mean that you are a pilot also?)

Comment: P.S.  A dynamic pressure reading won't tell you anything about an impending stall, you need an AOA gauge for that.  And for predicting inflight breakup due to overstress, (other than exceeding Vne) a G meter.

Comment: @JanHudec, any aircraft simple enough to not display GS will probably be low enough that IAS is as good as TAS.  In any case, the point of my answer is that it is easier to get TAS from IAS than from PSI.

Answer (score 0):

Airspeed is a calibrated value based on ram air pressure as collected by the pitot tube or other sensor *minus* static pressure, which is the ambient pressure of the air. If you don't subtract static pressure then your airspeed figures will be inaccurate. Think of it this way, an airplane parked in still air should have an airspeed of zero, if your airspeed indicator reads static pressure then the airspeed will have an indication despite there being no dynamic pressure. This inaccuracy will vary with changes in the static pressure, so you'll never really know what your airspeed is, which is critical for safety.

Comment: Yes, good point, thanks @Bianfable.

Comment: You seem to not comprehend the question. Dynamic pressure is total pressure minus static pressure.

Comment: I answered my interpretation of your question, I suggest you clarify the question so you get better answers. @Abdullah

Comment: It would be really interesting to see how a *mechanical* airspeed indicator makes the $\sqrt{P}$ adjustment.  Indicated is very close to true speed at sea level at standard conditions.